# Why is a Constant Being Set That is Not Subsequently Used

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code in my app, some of which I found online in a tutorial somewhere. Everything seems to work okay, but I don't understand something. In the line that starts "let dataDescription = document...." I don't understand what exactly that is doing, since "dataDescription" is never subsequently used anywhere. I understand that "document.data().map..." is retrieving the data from the document, but then "dataDescription" is never used anywhere after that. I just want to understand what's happening. I do find a lot of code online to use, but I hate just using it without understanding what's going on.

```
let docRef = db.collection("jammers").document(userDocumentID)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                let data = document.data()

                //Code for saving or deleting Sings field
                if (data!["Sings"] != nil) //If Sings field exists
                {
                    if self.singsSwitch.isOn //If the switch is set to on
                    {
                        //Update Sings field
                        docRef.updateData(["Sings": true])
                    }
```

Comment: Most likely it's a forgotten debugging statement. The whole code is not very nice - inconsistent braces, force unwrapping when not needed, unnecessary parentheses around `if` conditions...

Comment: That's what it was. I'm new to programming, so I'm not surprised you find the code to be not very nice. I'm still learning.